# Singleton with static member instance

Tags: c++, performance, design-patterns

I've got a Singleton implementation where I am not sure which drawbacks it contains. Could anybody tell me how good this implementation is?

```
template <class Child>
class Singleton {

public:

    inline static Child& Instance() {   
        return Instance_;
    }

    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;

    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;

protected:

    Singleton() = default;

private:

    static Child Instance_;

};

template <typename Child> Child Singleton<Child>::Instance_;
```

I know of a Singleton implementation by Scott Meyers that defines the static `Instance_` inside the `GetInstance()` function.

```
inline static Child& Instance() {   
    static Child Instance_;
    return Instance_;
}
```

But isn't there additional overhead involved, because it has to check every time the function is invoked whether `Instance_` has already been initialized.

Comment: Might be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Only difference at time when object is getting created. In your case, object will be constructed before main function, Meyers'es trick shows delayed construction. About performance, it's least part you should care about. As Meyers says - don't optimize unless profiler says so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution is prone to [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

A static class member is initialized together with all global static variables; before `main()`, in an unspecified order. If initialization of one static variable happens to reference another one, you get undefined behavior.

Using a static variable in function, however, gives you the special guarantee: the object will only be created when the function is executed for the first time. This means that you don't have to worry about initialization order (unless you create a cycle, obviously).

Regarding performance, the checking is implemented by compiler, so it's probably tuned extremely well. As always, if you're in doubt - benchmark.